# How can I generate a random 7-character alphanumeric string?

Tags: java

I did the stuff like this but not working. the base48Encode method parameter I have passed the current system time in milli secs

```
private static final String CHARACTER_SET = "23456789abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";

public static String base48Encode(double d) {
    Double num = Double.valueOf(d);
    Integer length = CHARACTER_SET.length();
    String encodeString = new String();
    while (num > length) {
        encodeString = CHARACTER_SET.charAt(num.intValue() % length) + encodeString;
        num = Math.ceil(new Double(num / length) - 1);
    }
    encodeString = CHARACTER_SET.charAt(num.intValue()) + encodeString;

    return encodeString;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-numbers-in-a-range-with-java

Comment: Are you asking for a random 7 digit number, or a random 7 character value? The title of your question and the content of it are conflicting.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, it should be mixture of alphanumeric, I won't get duplicate values in any scenario.

Comment: Have a look at [RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) from Apache Commons. You can probably use the randomAlphanumeric() method.

Comment: Your requirements as stated are contradictory. Random cannot be unique by definition.

Comment: I'd suggest renaming the method - "encode" implies a reversible process, which this is not.

Comment: @mustaccio correct, yet many unique id generators are based solemnly on random generators - UUID version 4 to name one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I won't get duplicate values in any scenario.

It's not possible to 100% guarantee a unique value (especially given a string of 7 characters) due to the [Birthday Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem). Given a character set containing 48 characters, selecting 7 at random, you'd have a 1% chance of collision after only 110,000 random values.

You can help mitigate this by doing two things.

1. Use a larger character set.
2. Increase the length of your random value.

Using a character set of 64 characters and selecting 10 at random would greatly decrease your chance of a collision, down to a 1% after 160,000,000 random values.

Rather than using `currentTimeMillis` to generate a value, which would cause a collision if you generated two values within the same millisecond, I'd suggest just using the `Random` class (which is seeded from the current time down to the nanosecond).

```
private static final String CHARACTER_SET = "23456789abcdefghijkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
private static Random rnd = new Random();

public static String randomString(int length){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        builder.append(CHARACTER_SET.charAt(rnd.nextInt(CHARACTER_SET.length())));
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: thanks Syon! I agree, It's not possible to 100% guarantee a unique value (especially given a string of 7 characters)